# Text too much for listView?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to have a list with maybe 4 lines of text in front of the image. The image is not properly underneath each other and the text if its too long it goes outside the layout view of it. and link for picture of the issue; https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJwQg.png

> How would i fix the images alignment issues? what can i do about the
>   text?

SingleList;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

ListClass;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class listClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public listClass(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {

    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "SOMETHING ALWYAS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ",
            "ALWYAS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWYAS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS "
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.pol,};
[enter image description here][1]


    Handler handler;
    Button button;
    headercode header;
    extra ex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        Handler handle = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ahmed, options);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
            }



        };



        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        listClass adapter = new
                listClass(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a textview with the following attributes to keep the lines within the screen.

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="100"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
```

Then, to overlay the TextView on the ImageView, I'd recommend replacing the TableLayout with a RelativeLayout, which adds all Views to the top left corner if no other attributes are specified (allowing views to stack on top of each other). TableLayout doesn't allow stacking, and simply adds the next view to the next available space.